# Internal Repository Setup

Tags: git, dvcs

I have jumped on the GIT bandwagon lately. I am confused about which DVCS hosting to use. I am in a notion that i can setup my own thing on a dedicated/vps server.

So, my question is that, how to setup my own internal remote repository management system on the dedicated server that i have?

Please guide.

Regards

Comment: What operating system is your server running?

Comment: Or you could follow the world and use github. For small money they'll host private repos too. And you get backup for free of (what I imagine is) your most important asset: your source.

Comment: It is running on CentOS release 6.2 (Final).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server run the following command in a directory you want to use...

```
git init --bare
```

This creates an empty/bare repository on the server.

On the client run the following command in an existing git repository (assume you know how to do this)...

```
git remote add myserver <url/path>
```

This adds a remote / link to your server. Path can be local, remote (http, ssh, etc).

- On a local file system use: ~/myrepo/example.git
- Using ssh: ssh://username@example.org/~/myrepo/example.git
- Using http: http://username@example.org/myrepo/example.git

For more info on setting up git over ssh see the following [article](http://fclose.com/b/linux/366/set-up-git-server-through-ssh-connection/).

To push code to your server do the following...

```
git push myserver master
```

This pushes your commits up to the remote server. Where 'myserver' is the alias you gave to your remote location

```
git pull myserver master
```

With git pull you download/pull all the commits from the server.

**Edit** Github is great and has a lot of additional features, but it is good to know how to set up a git repository yourself.

Comment: what exactly will come in <url/path> ? I have the shell access to the server. Can you please elaborate a bit...

Comment: Added example paths and a link to setting up git over SSH.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Gitosis](https://github.com/res0nat0r/gitosis), it makes setting up repositories very easy. You can find a quick tutorial on their github page (see link).